# Display current date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, date

I am using website builder called 'clickfunnels', and they don't support feature that would allow me to display current date. But, I can add custom HTML to it.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to show on website current date in format: dd/mm/yyyy

Currently I've tried this:

```
<p id="date"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

And this works, but it displays date likes this:

> Sat Sep 12 2015 16:40:10 GMT+0200 (Timezone.... )

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's one way. You have to get the individual components from the date object (day, month & year) and then build and format the string however you wish.

```js
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: Okay.. this works, but shows day as 6th of the month, when its 12th?

Comment: Woah.. work awesome..Quick question, if its not too much.. Is it possible to make it like this: 12 September 2015 ?

Comment: You can, but you need a bit more work.  You'll have to create an array with the month names: January = 0, February = 1 ... December = 11.  Then you display the array element in place of the 'm' variable.  Work on it yourself a little and if you get stuck you can post a new question.

Comment: @Miqro Here is a jsfiddle that will display like you want: https://jsfiddle.net/2c8uogff/

Answer (score 25):

Use [`Date::toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString()
= "9/13/2015"
```

You don't need to set innerHTML, just by writing

```
<p>
<script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script>
</p>
```

will work.

[image: supportness]

P.S.

```
new Date().toDateString()
= "Sun Sep 13 2015"
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use

```
<input type='date' id='hasta' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'>
```

that works well

Comment: That's PHP, not HTML (or JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

```js
var currentDate  = new Date(),
    currentDay   = currentDate.getDate() < 10 
                 ? '0' + currentDate.getDate() 
                 : currentDate.getDate(),
    currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() < 9 
                 ? '0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) 
                 : (currentDate.getMonth() + 1);

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = currentDay + '/' + currentMonth + '/' +  currentDate.getFullYear();
```

You can read more about [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

```
<p>Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p><script>var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML=dt.toLocaleString();</script>
```

Comment: This appears to be use the same technique as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540850/215552)...

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script >
window.onload = setInterval(clock,1000);
function clock()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var date = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var monthArr = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December"];
    month = monthArr[month];
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=date+" "+month+", "+year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="date" type="date" /> 
<script>
var date = new Date();
var currentDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
var currentTime = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();

document.getElementById('date').value = currentDate;
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```