# Hello, Please i am using ajax to display date in django template it is giving me long unformatted date

Tags: django, ajax

for example

var temp="

**"+response.messages[key].date+"**

result: 2021-10-02T09:53:27.896Z

how do I make it to show the same as django  --   {{date|timesince}}

Comment: what format do you want ? Show an example and we can find answer

Comment: var temp="<div style='margin-bottom: 10px; height: auto;' class='containerchat'><p><b>"+response.messages[key].person+"</b><br>"+response.messages[key].message_notes+"<span class='time-right'>"+response.messages[key].date+"</span></p></div>";

Comment: The above is my ajax script as you can see

Comment: response .messages[key].date    returns a string of long formatted time
like 2021-10-02T09:53:27.896Z. how do i make it a normal period like 2days ago or 21/10/2021

Comment: could you please try to show your views.py and your template

Comment: @user16728502 this will solve our problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/32540044/14777930